Is it possible to connect list workflows between parent site and sub-site?
I am trying to create a workflow on SharePoint Designer 2016 that creates a list item in a subset when a certain criteria is met. Is this possible?
Here's some context:
Site1 = parent site
Site2 = sub-site
Ideally, I want a workflow to create an item in Site2 when a new list item is created on Site1.
I have tried everything, but have not been able to figure it out. I have tried calling HTTP web services, scraping strings from an email sent by Site1, and many others.
Can someone please offer some assistance on this?
Thanks.
